# Modify the file before it opens and then open it in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

The site has a `<a/>` link with the `href` attribute.
If you click on it, the file specified in the `href` will open in a new tab.
I need javascript or jQuery that will modify the file before it opens and then open it in a new tab.

---

Ok. more info. Sorry for my bad English.
There is an element on the page:

```
<a href="https://example.com/something.user.css" target="_blank">Install usercss</a>
```

If you click on it the browser will open a new tab with this file and the Stylus extension offer to install this style. But this style is broken.
I want to write userscript that will download this file, delete broken part in it and open it in the new tab so that the Stylus pick it up and offer to install the fixed style.

Comment: Please show any research you've done into the issue and any code you've attempted.

Comment: Give more details (like what kind of file...), show an example of what you have done so far...

Answer (score 0):

the codes I write are very general, remember that. I wrote it because you didn't specify exactly what you wanted. you may not specify it with javascript to open a separate page. the target parameter will work.

Html:

```
<a href="#" id="link">click it</a> // your link in the page
```

Javascript:

```
 const link = document.getElementById("link");
 changeHref(link, "go somewhere", true);

 function changeHref(link, href, blank) {
 link.addEventListener("click", () => {
    link.setAttribute("href", "go somewhere");
    blank && link.setAttribute("target", "_blank"); // if attribute true thats block works
    })
};
```

when you create a function in this way, you can give it any parameter you want and execute it for any link you want.

Good luck!

Comment: How does this "modify the file before it opens and then open it in a new tab"? Also, you can open a separate window using `window.open(url)`, which in tabbed browsers generally opens a tab.